# Configuring Hubs and Namespaces in Azure Notification Hub

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

We have different bundle ids for public and Enterprise versions of our xamarin forms app and it has both android and iOS versions. What would be the recommended configuration of namespaces and hubs. Would the below approach work?

### Public App

Namespace 1 - Hub 1 - Dev

Namespace 1 - Hub 2 - Prod

### Enterprise App (distributed through MDM)

Namespace 2 - Hub 3 - Dev

Namespace 2 - Hub 4 - Prod

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is? You don't know how to configure hubs or namespace in azure notification hub? If yes, please take a look:[Set up Push Notification Services and Azure Notification Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#set-up-push-notification-services-and-azure-notification-hub)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT My question is how do we segregate different environments of the app - Dev and Prod. Should it be different hubs in the same namespace or two different namespaces itself?

Comment: Whatever you use different hubs in same namespace or two different namesapces, it all works, but for the convenience of management, I suggest you can use two different hub in same namespace.